# Busca no banco de dados via AJAX c/ jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estou com um cadastro de usuário em que digito um CPF e quando esse campo perde o foco, o campo nome é preenchido c/ o usuário correspondente àquele CPF. Essa busca no banco estou fazendo c/ jQuery e AJAX. Já fiz várias pesquisas (inclusive aqui no SO), mas até agora não consegui resolver. O q está acontecendo é q **o campo nome continua em branco após o CPF perder o foco**, ou seja, não carrega o nome do usuário. Segue o código em PHP:

***Edit***: Tentei o método $.ajax() e continua sem aparecer nada; e agora apareceu uma msg de erro no navegador, que pelo o q entendi, tem a ver com as tags HTML (diz q espera uma expressão, mas foi encontrado uma tag, mas não sei q expressão é essa)[image: Erro jQuery]

**buscarjQuery.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Formulecs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#cpf").blur(function(){
                /*$.get("search_cpf.php", function(resultado){
                    $("#nome").html(resultado);

                });*/
                //get input value
                var cpf = $("#cpf").val();
                if (cpf == '') $("#nome").val("CPF vazio, favor preencher");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    async: "true",
                    url: "search_cpf_mysqli.php",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {cpf:cpf},
                    success: function(data){

                        //debug result console
                        console.log(data); 

                        //set input value
                        $("#nome").val(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput-1.1.4.pack.js"/></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="found.php">
        <label for="cpf">CPF</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" required><br><br>

        <label for="nome">Nome</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" size="50" readonly><br><br>
        <button class="button">Buscar no banco</button>
    </form>
    <br><hr><br>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.php" type="button" role="button">Voltar para início</a>
    </nav>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

**search_cpf.php**

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_jquery_ajax");

    if (isset($_GET["cpf"])) {
        $query = "SELECT nome FROM table_name_cpf WHERE cpf = '$_GET["cpf"]'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $output = $row["nome"];
            }
        }
    } else {
        $output = "Cliente não cadastrado";
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Não manjo mt de php mas acho que tu tem que dar um retorno e não um echo nesse caso.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer buscas de dados via AJAX c/ jQuery você pode utilizar a seguinte função `$.ajax`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#cpf").blur(function(){

        //get input value
        var cpf = $('#cpf').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: "true",
            url: "search_cpf.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {cpf:cpf},
            success: function(data){

                //debug result console
                console.log(data); 

                //set input value
                $("#nome").val(data);

            }

        });
    });
});
```